# Framing a small wooden shed on concrete foundation

Tags: framing, shed

I’m planning on building my own wooden shed since I can’t find a prebuilt one that’s the right size.

I am considering just starting with wall frames and screwing those directly into concrete. Any drawbacks to this or should I create a floor first? Only thing I can think of is it’s possible for moisture to come inside from underneath the framing.

And second thing, when framing the wall with the door opening, should the bottom part where the door will be have a running 2x4 across?  I’m thinking that would stabilize the wall more plus I wouldn’t need a transition under the door.

Comment: Would use pressure treated lumber on the cement.  If stuff(metal, bag materials) inside is affected by humidly/damp conditions a floor would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure Treated (PT) Bottom plate between the Concrete and the Upright Studs.

The Flooring is really dependent on what’s in it, how the sides of the slab are on the outside, the thickness of the slab.

On the outside you typically want 2+ Inches of the slab showing before the siding starts.

If you add a Floor, you could put Pressure treated on its side every 16” and use some Exterior 3/4” Ply for the flooring. Put some plastic and or ridged foam insulation under/between PT.

Use Tapcons or other concrete Anchors for the attaching the PT to the Concrete. (Predrill the holes with a Rotohammer drill in the concrete.)

If no Flooring, then no Sill place where the Door is. The doors typically sit on the slab.   If adding the Flooring, then Yes, the door would have a continuous sill plate and the 3/4” ply would be on top of that sill plate too and the door on top of the plywood.